# How to convert SCSS to CSS automatically

Tags: css, sass

How can I set up Gulp to automatically convert my ".scss" code into standard CSS? Currently, I need to run a terminal command each time I want to compile, but I'd like to avoid having to do that repeatedly.

Comment: You using windows?

Comment: https://prepros.io/ This will generate css on save of your scss file

Comment: For Mac : http://unmatchedstyle.com/news/setting-up-codekit-for-sass.php

Comment: Or, if you are using node, then node-sass : https://github.com/sass/node-sass

Comment: yes! i'm suing window

Comment: Prepros should be good.

Comment: Can it done using PHP ??

Comment: Because I only want to simple work to convert to .scss to .css. the prepros is to advanced

Comment: Hello Biswas....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use

```
sass --watch app/sass:public/stylesheets
```

this where:

`app/sass` is location of scss files and `public/stylesheets` location where you want to have css. It will automatically convert scss to css after each save of the sass files.

More details here: http://sass-lang.com/guide